# Runtime error concerning creating a new object

Tags: c++, runtime

I am attempting to write a simple game lobby program (no actual networking, just a simulation.) and I am running into a runtime error while testing my program and I have no idea how to go about fixing it. (I am fairly new to programming.)

My error is that when I go to cin a new player node into the lobby, the program accepts the first two player names that I input but on the third attempt I type a new name, and press enter but the cursor goes to a new line instead of entering the new node. I suspect the problem is somewhere in the Lobby::Add function but I'm not sure where. Any help or ideas would be appreciated. Thank you =).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Player
{
public:

    Player(const string& name = "");
    string GetName() const;
    Player* GetNext() const;
    void SetNext(Player* next);

private:
    string m_Name;
    Player* m_pNext;
};

Player::Player(const string& name):
    m_Name(name),
    m_pNext(0)
{}

string Player::GetName() const
{
    return m_Name;
}

Player* Player::GetNext() const
{
    return m_pNext;
}

void Player::SetNext(Player* next)
{
    m_pNext = next;
}

class Lobby
{
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Lobby& aLobby);

public:
    Lobby();
    ~Lobby();
    void Add();
    void Remove();
    void Clear();

private:
    Player* m_pHead;
};

Lobby::Lobby():
m_pHead(0)
{}

Lobby::~Lobby()
{
    Clear();
}

void Lobby::Add()
{
    // Create a new player node
    cout << "Please enter the name of new player: ";
    string name;
    cin >> name;
    Player* pNewPlayer = new Player(name);

    //If list is empty make head of list this new player
    if (m_pHead == 0)
    {
        m_pHead = pNewPlayer;
    } 

    else
    {
        Player* pIter = m_pHead;

        while(pIter->GetNext() != 0)
        {
            pIter->GetNext();
        }

        pIter->SetNext(pNewPlayer);
    }
}

void Lobby::Remove()
{
    if(m_pHead == 0)
    {
        cout << "The game lobby is empty, there are no players to remove!\n\n";
    }

    else
    {
        Player* pTemp = m_pHead;
        m_pHead = m_pHead->GetNext();
        delete pTemp;
    }
}

void Lobby::Clear()
{
    while(m_pHead != 0)
    {
        Remove();
    }
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Lobby& aLobby)
{
    Player* pIter = aLobby.m_pHead;

    cout << "Here's who is in the game lobby: \n";

    if (pIter == 0)
    {
        cout << "The lobby is empty.\n";
    }

    else
    {
        while(pIter != 0)
        {
            os << pIter->GetName() << endl;
            pIter = pIter->GetNext();
        }
    }

    return os;
}

int main()
{
    Lobby myLobby;
    int choice;

    do
    {
        cout << myLobby;
        cout << "\nWelcome to the game lobby!\n";
        cout << "Please enter a choice.\n";
        cout << "0 - Quit the program.\n";
        cout << "1 - Add a player to the lobby.\n";
        cout << "2 - Remove a player from the lobby.\n";
        cout << "3 - Clear the lobby.\n\n";

        cout << "Choice: ";
        cin >> choice;

        switch(choice)
        {
            case 0: cout << "Goodbye!"; break;
            case 1: myLobby.Add(); break;
            case 2: myLobby.Remove(); break;
            case 3: myLobby.Clear(); break;
            default: cout << "Please enter a valid choice.\n"; break;
        }

    }while(choice != 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's an awful lot of code.  Can you construct a simpler example that demonstrates the same problem?

Comment: Ever heard of a debugger? Also, you have to flush output when prompting a user for something.

Comment: Have you considered using `std::list` or `std::deque` instead of implementing your own linked list?

Comment: @VladLazarenko - by default, `cin` and `cout` are synchronized. You don't need to flush after a prompt.

Comment: @lethal-guitar

I'm following the methods used in a text book so I have to say I'm not sure how to use std::list or std::deque.

Comment: @PeteBecker But the debugger advice remains. Jammin, this is a problem to solve using a debugger in your program, not here.

Comment: @PeteBecker

I'm running OS X 10.5 and using Netbeans 6.8 as my IDE, is there any good debuggers that will run on my system? I tried to use the debugger that comes with Netbeans but it gives me an error that says "external terminal failed to launch", also, I cannot run my projects through netbeans I have to clean/build then manually open the source file. Not sure if that is relevant or helps in any way.

Comment: If you absolutely cannot get a debugger to run, you can do "printf debugging": Simply insert `cout` statements at relevant points in your code, and output the values of relevant variables. Although please be aware that this is more of a crutch than a solution, and rather frowned upon. You should really learn how to debug properly, it will help you a lot in the long term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an endless loop when adding. You call `GetNext()` but forgot to assign the result to `pIter`.

I tend to agree with what others said though, you need to learn how to use a debugger. It also helps reducing problematic code to the smallest piece of code before posting. In many cases, this already allows you to find the problem yourself. In your code, you should have replaced the input from `std::cin` with just fixed values so people don't have to guess what they need to input.

Good luck!

Uli

Comment: @Uli

Thanks, got it working. I'm working on getting some better hardware and a more current OS to work with, hopefully then my debugger will be working. Also, Thanks for the advice I will keep it in mind when I post future questions.